# Shiny - create list of numeric inputs based on variable names loaded from a file

Tags: user-interface, shiny, user-input

I would like to load a CSV file with inside a list of variable names such as

```
"var_A", "var_B", "var_C"
```

and create in the GUI a list of numeric inputs for each variable name. I guess I need to pass by `uiOutput` function but no idea to do that. here's a kinda draft of what I'm trying to do

```
ui <- bootstrapPage(
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File', accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv'))

    # list of numeric inputs
    #uiOutput("list_numeric_inputs")
   )

server <- function(input,output) {

  data_set <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    data_set<-read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=F)
  })

  # # list of numeric inputs
  # output$list_numeric_inputs <- renderUI({
  #   # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
  #   if(is.null(input$data_set()))
  #     return()
  #   
  #   # Get the data set value for variable name
  #   for (i in 1:nrow(data_set)) {
  #     numericInput("...", paste0(data_set[i]), value = 0.)
  #   }
  # })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your example not working ( havent inputs for `header=input$header,sep=input$sep, quote=input$quote`)

2)You havent `input$dataset` only `data_set <- reactive`

3) So working one :

```
library(shiny)
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File', accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv')),

  # list of numeric inputs
  uiOutput("list_numeric_inputs")
)

server <- function(input,output) {

  data_set <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    data_set<-read.csv(inFile$datapath,header = F)
  })

   # list of numeric inputs
   output$list_numeric_inputs <- renderUI({
     # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
     if(is.null(data_set()))
       return()

   # Get the data set value for variable name
     lapply(data_set(),function(i){
       numericInput(paste0(i,"_ID"), i, value = 0.)
     }
   ) 
   })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: 1) you are right sorry, I started from a copy and paste of a similar problem
2) right
3) great! I'm studying it now and try to apply on my code
4) thanks a lot!